# Combinatorics - homework

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've got the following problem which I am slightly confused on two parts and wondering if anyone could help me better understand how to solve this:

```
A new battery’s voltage may be acceptable (A) or unacceptable (U). 
A certain flashlight requires two batteries, so batteries will be independently selected and tested until two acceptable ones have been found. 
Suppose that 90% of all batteries have acceptable voltages. Let Y denote the number of batteries that must be tested.

a.What is p(2), that is, P(Y=2)?

b.What is p(3)? [Hint:There are two different outcomes that result in Y=3]

c. To have Y=5 , what must be true of the fifth battery selected? List the four outcomes for which Y=5 and then determine p(5).
```

I understood part a, but I'm stuck on b and c. Below is what I've got for parts b and c:

b.
$P(3) = P(1) \times P(1) \times P(1) $

c.

$AUUUA$

$UAUUA$

$UUAUA$

$UUUAA$

$P(5) = 0.1^3 \times 0.9 \times 4 $

Comment: You have the right method for c), and b) uses the same idea. There are two possibilities, AUA and UAA. Note that in c) each probability is $(0.1)^3(0.9)^2$. Multiply by $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For b, you are asked for the probability that the second good battery is the third one tested.  How many bad batteries does that require?  Your listing for part c indicates you understand it.  Please note that $p$ and $P$ are different-the question uses $p$ and you are using $P$.  The probability in b should look close to your probability in c.  The probability in c is almost correct, but you have two good batteries, not one.

Comment: I think I just got it, I've got the following for b and c now: for b I have $P(3)=.1 \times .9^2 \times 2 = .162  $ and for part c I have $P(5) = .1^3 \times .9^2 \times 4 = .324 $

Comment: It makes sense now, however the one thing that confuses me slightly is that the answer at the back of the book for part c states that the answer is supposed to be .00405 I'm going to assume that is a typo on the book, unless I still have it wrong somehow?

Comment: That is correct for b.  For c, the numeric value is 100 times too large, but that still doesn't match the book.  I think you missed the exponent on $0.1$.  It looks like they have a factor $5$ instead of $4$, but your $4$ is correct.